# Show number of DataGrid rows as a control and have it update correctly

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events, binding

I have a DataGrid which is bound to an ObservableCollection and I'd like a control on my form (like a status bar, for eg.) which shows the collection count.
Sounds simple, but I've been researching for hours to find the right way to do it.

At the moment, I've landed on handling the CollectionChanged event (part of the ObservableCollection), using the below three lines of code:

```
Public Sub ColChanged(sender As Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Handles perCol.people.CollectionChanged
    counter.Text = perCol.people.Count & " people added."
End Sub
```

***My problem is*** I get [this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vetuk.jpg) stating, *"'Handles' in classes must specify a 'WithEvents' variable, 'MyBase', 'MyClass' or 'Me' qualified with a single identifier."* on the `percol.people` part of the code, even though all of the variables use the 'WithEvents' keyword.

What am I missing? Is there a better way of doing this?
I've tried binding the `textblock.text` property to a variable in one of my classes but I can't get that to work somehow.

For context, I've pasted my code below.

**MainWindow.xaml.vb**

```
Imports WpfApp1.PersonCollection
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Class MainWindow
    Public WithEvents perCol As New PersonCollection

    Private Sub Add_btn_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Add_btn.Click
        If FirstName_tb.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("No first name specified.")
            Me.Activate()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If LastName_tb.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("No last name specified.")
            Me.Activate()
            Exit Sub
        End If
        perCol.AddPerson(New person(FirstName_tb.Text, LastName_tb.Text))
    End Sub

    Private Sub WindowName_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles WindowName.Loaded
        DataGrid.ItemsSource = perCol.people
    End Sub

    Public Sub ColChanged(sender As Object, e As NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs) Handles perCol.people.CollectionChanged
        counter.Text = perCol.people.Count & " people added."
    End Sub
End Class
```

**PersonCollection.vb**

```
Imports System.Collections.ObjectModel

Public Class PersonCollection
    Public WithEvents people As New ObservableCollection(Of person)
    Public Sub AddPerson(NewPerson As person)
        people.Add(NewPerson)
    End Sub

    Public Class person
        Public Property FirstName As String
        Public Property lastName As String
        Public Sub New(First_Name As String, Last_Name As String)
            FirstName = First_Name
            lastName = Last_Name
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" x:Name="WindowName">

    <Window.Resources>
        <local:PersonCollection x:Key="PersonSource"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="First Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="26,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97"/>
        <Label Content="Last Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="38" Margin="26,83,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="FirstName_tb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="100,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="LastName_tb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="36" Margin="100,83,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156"/>
        <Button x:Name="Add_btn" Content="Add" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="33" Margin="34,148,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="132"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="counter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="34,201,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="47" Width="244"/>

        <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="302" Margin="317,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="426" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonSource, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: `<TextBlock x:Name="counter" Text="{Binding Items.Count, ElementName=DataGrid, StringFormat={}{0} people added}" .../>`. You don't need that `ColChanged` event handler. You don't need `x:Name="counter" ` either; I only left that in so you'd know I meant for you to make the changes to that textbox.

Comment: You should really start moving to MVVM and binding rather than writing in code-behind like old winforms.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys, I'll look intos starting with MVVM. As for your suggestion Ed, I've modified my code to match your comment but I'm still not seeing anything in the TextBlock at runtime. Perhaps it's now a DataGrid binding problem? The reason I say this is the DataGrid doesn't populate with new names added. XAML below.

Comment: `<Window.Resources>
        <local:PersonCollection x:Key="PersonSource"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    </Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="302" Margin="317,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="426" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonSource}}"/>
    <Grid>`

Comment: The above method for binding the DatGrid came from [this MS Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection)